Magento2 configurable product import issue
I am trying to configurable product import using csv file ..But I getting error like
1. Array ( [not visible individually] => 1 [catalog] => 2 [search] => 3 [catalog, search] => 4 ) in row(s): 1
2. Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 2 ) in row(s): 1
3. Array ( [product info column] => container1 [block after info column] => container2 ) in row(s): 1
4. Invalid format. in row(s): 1

my csv file code here ...
sku,store_view_code,attribute_set_code,product_type,categories,product_websites,name,description,short_description,weight,product_online,tax_class_name,visibility,price,special_price,special_price_from_date,special_price_to_date,url_key,meta_title,meta_keywords,meta_description,base_image,base_image_label,small_image,small_image_label,thumbnail_image,thumbnail_image_label,swatch_image,swatch_image_label,created_at,updated_at,new_from_date,new_to_date,display_product_options_in,map_price,msrp_price,map_enabled,gift_message_available,custom_design,custom_design_from,custom_design_to,custom_layout_update,page_layout,product_options_container,msrp_display_actual_price_type,country_of_manufacture,additional_attributes,qty,out_of_stock_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,allow_backorders,use_config_backorders,min_cart_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_cart_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_on_stock_below,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,website_id,related_skus,crosssell_skus,upsell_skus,additional_images,additional_image_labels,hide_from_product_page,bundle_price_type,bundle_sku_type,bundle_price_view,bundle_weight_type,bundle_values,configurable_variations,configurable_variation_labels,associated_skus
ZN-O67W-23JH-PROVA1,,Default,configurable,"Default Category/Uomo,Default Category/Uomo/Abbigliamento,Default Category/Oversize/Uomo,Default Category/Oversize/Uomo/Abbigliamento,Default Category/Uomo/Abbigliamento/Camicie",base,La Primula Verde Camicia di Lino Modello Estate PROVA 1,"<p>Bellissima Camicia in Puro Lino, ideale per la primavere e l'estate. Il modello estate, è l'unione tra la classica camicia di lino e la necessità di essere il più leggeri possibile per il caldo estivo. Questo capo ha l'ambizione di essere sempre nel luogo giusto. Elegante ma anche sportivo, con questa camicia non ti sentirai mai diverso. Questa camicia, commercializzata solo dalla Primula Verde, è disponibile dalla taglia S alla 3XL in molte colorazioni. Hai bisogno di aiuto con le taglie? Contattaci, potremmo aiutarti per capire la taglia giusta per te!</p>",,1,1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",1,,,,,,,,/3/1/31jw648N9DL.jpg,,/3/1/31jw648N9DL.jpg,,,,,,"29/01/23, 16:45","08/06/23, 08:47",,,Block after Info Column,,,,,,,,Italia,,0,,,,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,,"/3/1/31jw648N9DL.jpg,/6/1/61OBOaKKXxL.jpg,/3/1/31jw648N9DL._SL75_.jpg,/6/1/618pKZIiSJL.jpg",,,,,,,,,,"sku=lpv00001818,color=Verde,size=L|sku=lpv00001813,color=Verde,size=M|sku=lpv00001808,color=Verde,size=S|sku=lpv00001833,color=Verde,size=3XL|sku=lpv00001828,color=Verde,size=XXL|sku=lpv00001823,color=Verde,size=XL|sku=lpv00001822,color=Blu,size=XL|sku=lpv00001821,color=Blu,size=XL|sku=lpv00001814,color=Blu,size=M|sku=lpv00001817,color=Blu,size=L|sku=lpv00001816,color=Blu,size=L|sku=lpv00001809,color=Blu,size=S|sku=lpv00001812,color=Blu,size=M|sku=lpv00001811,color=Blu,size=M|sku=lpv00001834,color=Blu,size=3XL|sku=lpv00001807,color=Blu,size=S|sku=lpv00001829,color=Blu,size=XXL|sku=lpv00001831,color=Blu,size=3XL|sku=lpv00001832,color=Blu,size=3XL|sku=lpv00001824,color=Blu,size=XL|sku=lpv00001827,color=Blu,size=XXL|sku=lpv00001826,color=Blu,size=XXL|sku=lpv00001819,color=Blu,size=L|sku=lpv00001810,color=Bianco,size=M|sku=lpv00001805,color=Bianco,size=S|sku=lpv00001830,color=Bianco,size=3XL|sku=lpv00001825,color=Bianco,size=XXL|sku=lpv00001820,color=Bianco,size=XL|sku=lpv00001815,color=Bianco,size=L",,"PROVA1-size-S,PROVA1-size-M"

